# Remote Powershell for non-admin user in non-domain pc

Tags: windows, powershell, remote

I'm trying to achieve the following: I would like to run a remote powershell script on a computer that is not in a domain.

I've researched a lot and set up already all permissions/firewall rules etc that brings me to the following result.

When I try to run the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName thecomputer -ScriptBlock { $Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session } -credential regularuser
```

I get the following error:
*Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {4CB43D7F-7EEE-4906-8698-6
0DA1C38F2FE} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070005
 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).*

HOWEVER,

- when I add regularuser in the admin group on the remote pc, it works
- running the same command locally with regularuser (non admin) works fine
- also, when I try to run

  Invoke-Command -ComputerName thecomputer -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ } -credential regularuser

  it works perfectly.

I believe that all connectivity is set up correctly (it works as admin user, as well as a regularuser with a different script).

It seems a rights problem on the specific Microsoft.Update.Session COM object.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this (without resorting to an admin user).

I also tried disabling the firewall (long shot but read it on some other post), but same result.  Remote machine is Windows 10 professional.

Thank you in advance,
Wim

Comment: What happens when remote into the computer as the user and run the command $Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session manually?